# To pass scheduler object to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, scheduler

I'm trying to pass the scheduler object to another activity and stop the scheduler executor service. May I know the appropriate method to do this?

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //get date
        Date dateTime = new Date();
        String formattedDateTime = DATE_FORMAT.format(dateTime);
    }, 0, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //End of Scheduler
```

Comment: post the code and error message

Comment: Im trying to stop this scheduler on another activity and thanks for you quick response

Comment: how you stop scheduler object try to stop in the same activity

Answer (score 0):

I would use a global variable for this purpose and not try to pass the scheduler from one `Activity` to another. Just make your `scheduler` variable `public static` and you can access it from the second `Activity`.

However, passing the scheduler to another `Activity` won't allow you to stop it. What you need is the `ScheduledFuture` that is returned from the call to `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate()`. Store this in a `public static` variable and you can then cancel it from anywhere.

Comment: public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
  boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

  if (on == true ) {

    // cancel the scheduler
   scheduler.shutdown();

    } else {
           
    statusText.setText("CurrentStatus: ON");

        }. This is the part of my code and I'd try to shutdown the scheduler using toggle button in another activity but I couldn't stop the scheduler

Comment: Yes, OK. That should work (Sorry, I didn't see the `shutdown()` method in the documentation). Please don't post code in comments, it is ugly. If you have used the global (static) variable as I've indicated, please edit your original question and add the code you now have that doesn't work.